# How to animate a bar chart and then fade in labels above each bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to animate a bar chart. Animate in one bar after the other, and then fade in the labels above each bar but it's not animating.

[See the code here.](http://codepen.io/ameliarae/pen/rLjBxK)

HTML:

```
<table id="q-graph">
<caption>Quarterly Results</caption>
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th class="sent">Invoiced</th>
<th class="paid" id="cg">Collected</th>
  <button>click</button>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="qtr" id="q1">
<th scope="row">Q1</th>
<td class="sent bar" style="height: 111px;"><p>$18,450.00</p></td>
<td class="paid bar" style="height: 99px;"><p>$16,500.00</p></td>
</tr>
<tr class="qtr" id="q2">
<th scope="row">Q2</th>
<td class="sent bar" style="height: 206px;"><p>$34,340.72</p></td>
<td class="paid bar" style="height: 194px;"><p>$32,340.72</p></td>
</tr>
<tr class="qtr" id="q3">
<th scope="row">Q3</th>
<td class="sent bar" style="height: 259px;"><p>$43,145.52</p></td>
<td class="paid bar" style="height: 193px;"><p>$32,225.52</p></td>
</tr>
<tr class="qtr" id="q4">
<th scope="row">Q4</th>
<td class="sent bar" style="height: 110px;"><p>$18,415.96</p></td>
<td class="paid bar" style="height: 195px;"><p>$32,425.00</p></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<div id="ticks">
<div class="tick" style="height: 59px;"><p>$50,000</p></div>
<div class="tick" style="height: 59px;"><p>$40,000</p></div>
<div class="tick" style="height: 59px;"><p>$30,000</p></div>
<div class="tick" style="height: 59px;"><p>$20,000</p></div>
<div class="tick" style="height: 59px;"><p>$10,000</p></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 $(function grow(){
     $(".bar").each(function(){
        var length = $(this).height() + 'px';
       console.log(length);
        $('.bar').animate({'height':'auto'},
"slow", function(){
  $(p).fadeIn(1000);
        });
});
});
$('.bar').height(0);
$('document').ready(function(){
 grow();
});
```

Right now it's not showing anything. I want it to animate after the page is done loading. And have the labels above the bars fade in after the bars are done animating.

Comment: What output do you expect?Didn't get clear idea.

Comment: What do you mean output? I just expect the bars to animate up to their height on page load. Like this: http://codepen.io/CreativePunch/pen/AekEC